# Show that it is consistent with Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-restriction

[image]

Show that $$f(t)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k\cos(k\omega_0t-\varphi_k)$$ is equivalent to the Fourier series.

Comment: Use the formula for $\cos(x-y)$.